# Mongo Atlas filter by date is not working

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am using the the following query to filter dates greater than the 25th of May, but it does not work. In the UI I chose the $match operator

```
{
  query: {$date:{ $gte:ISODate('2022-05-25')}}
}
```

In fact in the resulting collection it returns also dates prior to the one that I have specified in the filter condition.
[image]

Can you point me to the exact query?

Comment: The name of the field you are filtering on is `date` (_not_ `$date`).

Comment: In the end I managed to solve it. By removing "query" and by using date instead of $date.